# Jquery focus out event

Tags: jquery

I've a textbox having focusout event on it.
whenever the textbox loses focus (Tab, mouse click on any other part of the form),based on certain conditions a user-written function disaplying an alert is called.

Now, my form also has a button, after filling the textbox when i click  the button focusOut event of textbox is called instead of the button click event.

how do i stop the foucusout event of the textbox being called on button click ?

```
 ("$textbox").focusout(function(){
validation;
alert("message");
});

("$btn").click(function(){
----
});
```

can any one help me?

Comment: Can you provide some more context? If this is for form validation then alerting on focusout of every textbox seems very unnecessary.  If it's just a summary that you want to display prior to form submission there are other (better) ways to achieve this.

Comment: this is some kind of additional validation, apart form normal validation for a textbox to be done before submitting the form. i need to display a confrim box to the user while he click or moves to next texbox or click on any other filed.

Answer (score 8):

I've changed your click event to a mousedown (so it fires first) and used a variable to track your click :

```
var buttonClicked = false;

$('#txt1').focusout(function(){
    if(!(buttonClicked)){
        alert('BlurEvent');
    }else{
        buttonClicked = false;
    }
});

$('#btn').mousedown(function(event){
    alert('ClickEvent');
    buttonClicked = true;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/924SZ/

**EDIT**

```
var buttonClicked = false;

$('#txt1').focusout(function(){
    if(!(buttonClicked)){
        // do normal focusout code.
    }else{
        // button was clicked - dont execute some code.
        buttonClicked = false;
    }
    //this always executes regardless of focusout or button click
    var reply =confirm("Are you happy with the input?");
});

$('#btn').mousedown(function(event){

    buttonClicked = true;
});
```

Comment: Hi, if you see in your code, if i type anything in the txtbox and click on button first focusout alert is called and then click event. what i need is the focusout event shud not be called at all..only the button event shud be called.

Comment: since we're using the `mousedown` event, it is called first before the `focusout` which will happen after the `mouseup`. using a variable we eliminate the `focusout` function from executing. ie. If we click the button when the textbox has focus, `alert('BlurEvent')` doesn't fire.

Comment: We also eliminate the ability to do anything other than click on the button with the mouse...

Comment: is ther any way that i can avoid the alert ('blurevent') to be displayed on the screen.

Comment: hmmm. ill assume you dont mean the actual alert? because you can comment out or remove the alert entirely `//alert('BlurEvent')` it is just used as an example of what fires.

Comment: according to my code, i need to display a confirm box on textbxox focusout, this confirmbox should get fired when i click on the button click. any idea to supress this ?

Comment: i have edited a second version with some comments - is this what you need?

Answer (score 0):

Do you not get the `focusout` event triggering followed by the button `click` event?

Maybe the `alert` is preventing the button `click` from completing.

Try removing the `alert` to test if both events trigger.

Update:

Maybe a `mousedown` event will work instead of `click` as this will register on the `mousedown` rather than on the `mouseup` event that `click` will trigger on.

Comment: Hi, the alert inside the focusout is mandatory. Only the focusout event of the textbox is called but not the button click event. is there any chance to stop the textbox focusout event to stop from being called on button click.

Comment: The trouble is that the `focusout` will occur on the `mousedown` of the button `click` event but the button click may not happen until a `mouseup` event which might be being stopped by the alert. I only suggest temporarily removing this to confirm if that is the cause of the problem.

Comment: i tried with mouse down event, it didnt help i can still get the alert of focus out.. i don't want this alert to be displayed.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can do that as the focusout happens before the click event. You'd have to flag soemthing with mousedown and then let the focusout pick up on that but focusout may always happen first which may not allow this.

Answer (score 0):

I think the JQuery selector works with `$`. So IMO you are this is the only mistake you are doing here is wrongly placing the '$' dollar sign.

How about this. (assuming the `TextBox` has `class="textbox"` and `Button` has the `class='btn'`)

```
$(".textbox").focusout(function(){
    alert('MsgBox');
});

$(".btn").click(function(){
    alert('Button');    
});
```

Change the selector like following if you have `ID`s instead of `class`

```
$("#textbox") AND $("#btn")
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dAa2R/6/

Comment: the problem is the focusout is still firing which is causing a popup on the OPs application.